# Merge all files and grab particular column data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have many files in a folder. Below is the sample one.

abc.csv

| Seller | Vaule |
| --- | --- |
| Hari | 2 |
| Om | 12 |
| Cat | 0 |
| Mat | 14 |
| John | 0 |

Another table as -
bcd.csv

| Seller | Vaule |
| --- | --- |
| Hari | 0 |
| Om | 12 |
| Cat | 2 |
| Mat | 14 |
| John | 4 |

I have the same type csv files in my folder and I would like to merge all of them and keep the seller if its value = 0.

My expected output would be -

Final table -

| Seller | Vaule |
| --- | --- |
| Hari | 0 |
| Cat | 0 |
| John | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and filter (for example with [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)), optionally dropping duplicates ([`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)):

```
out = (pd.concat([abc, bcd]).query('Vaule == 0')
         .drop_duplicates(['Seller', 'Vaule']) # optional
      )
```

Output:

```
  Seller  Vaule
2    Cat      0
4   John      0
0   Hari      0
```